# Javascript function does not work for multiple circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

This querySelectorAll does not work for multiple circular progress bar. When I use querySelector it works for only one circle. How can i use this function for multiple circular progress bar.
Again, why this error -> "Uncaught TypeError: circle.getAttribute is not a function" ?

```js
   const circle = document.querySelectorAll(".progress");
    const number = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-percent");
    const val = circle.getAttribute("data-value");
    let counter = 0;
    let cir = 377;

    setInterval(() => {
      if (counter == val) {
        clearInterval();
      } else {
        counter += 1;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = (cir - (cir / 100) * val);
        number.innerHTML = counter;
      }
    }, 25);
```

```css
   body {
      background-color: #f50057;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .progress {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2;
      stroke-dasharray: 377;
      stroke-dashoffset: 377;
      transition: 2.5s ease-out;
    }

    .progress-percent {
      color: #fff;

    }
```

```html
  <section>
    <div>
      <svg>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="80"></circle>
      </svg>
      <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <svg>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="90"></circle>
      </svg>
      <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <svg>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
        <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="70"></circle>
      </svg>
      <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: If [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns an array-like nodelist, how do you think `circle.style` is going to work? You'll need [to iterate over the nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and apply the style circle by circle.

Comment: setInterval(() => {
      for(var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++){
      if (counter == val) {
        clearInterval();
      } else {
        counter += 1;
        circle[i].style.strokeDashoffset = (cir - (cir / 100) * val);
        number[i].innerHTML = counter;
      }
    }
    }, 25); Do you mean like that? I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

unlike `.querySelector`, `.querySelectorAll` returns many results. The previous actions that you would call on a single circle will not automatically apply to each of your circles. However, you can use the `.forEach` method and pass a function with each item as an argument.

you can read more about `.forEach` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If you have any questions, please ask. Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".progress");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-percent");

const cir = 377;
circles.forEach((circle, index) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const val = circle.getAttribute("data-value");
    setInterval(() => {
        if (counter == val) {
            clearInterval();
        } else {
            counter += 1;
            circle.style.strokeDashoffset = (cir - (cir / 100) * val);
            numbers[index].innerHTML = counter;
        }
    }, 25);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f50057;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.progress {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-dasharray: 377;
    stroke-dashoffset: 377;
    transition: 2.5s ease-out;
}

.progress-percent {
    color: #fff;

}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <svg>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="80"></circle>
        </svg>
        <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="90"></circle>
        </svg>
        <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
            <circle r="60" cx="60" cy="60" class="progress" data-value="70"></circle>
        </svg>
        <p><span class="progress-percent"></span>%</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It is really helpful to me. If these "counter += 1;
            circle.style.strokeDashoffset = (cir - (cir / 100) * val); " two will work on scroll of the page, then how can i arrange this js function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you need other functionality including variable manipulation tied to the scroll event I would need more information to give you a good answer  It might be worth making a new question if you have different issues / errors in connecting your function to the scroll event. If my answer satisfies your question I would appreciate you accepting the answer